# Possibilities for changing one $1024$ banknote to banknotes from $\{2^i: i = 0,\ldots,9 \} $

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilities do there exist to change one banknote $1024$ to denominations from the set set $\left\{2^i: i = 0,...,9 \right\} $.

I think that there really are a lot, but I don't have any idea on how to calculate it. I will be grateful for any help and hints.

Comment: Have you tried smaller values to see what happens?

Comment: Look into dynamic programming... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I present a modest contribution. Suppose we treat the problem of decomposing $2^n$ into sums of powers of two excluding the trivial solution $2^n=2^n.$ This can be solved by dynamic programming, here is the algorithm.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

my %memo;

sub change {
    my ($val, $mxpow) = @_;

    my $key = "$val-$mxpow";
    return $memo{$key} if exists $memo{$key};

    my $res = 0;
    my $inc = 2 ** $mxpow;

    if($mxpow>0){
      my $s = 0;
      while($s <= $val){
          $res += change($val-$s, $mxpow-1);
          $s += $inc;
      }
    }
    else{
      $res = 1;
    }

    $memo{$key} = $res;
    return $res;
}


MAIN: {
    my $max = shift || 10;


    my @res;
    for(my $n=1; $n<=$max; $n++){
      push @res, change(2**$n, $n-1);
    }

    print join(', ', @res) . "\n";
}
```

This algorithm will produce the following sequence:
$$1, 3, 9, 35, 201, 1827, 27337, 692003, 30251721, \\2320518947, 316359580361, 77477180493603,\ldots $$
which is [A125792 from the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A125792). You may consult this link for additional references about this problem, including a recurrence for the terms of the sequence.

In particular we have that the count for $2^{10}$ ($n=10$) is
$$2320518947.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $N(x)$ return the number of ways to write $2^x$ as an ordered sum of powers of two less than or equal to $2^{x-1}$.

If there are $n$ ways to write $2^k$ as the ordered sum of powers of two less than or equal to  $2^{k-1}$, then how many ways are there to write $2^{k+1}$ as the ordered sum of powers of two less than or equal to $2^k$? In other words, if $N(k)=n$, what is $N(k+1)$?

Since $2^{k+1} = 2^k + 2^k$, each of the $2^k$-sized halves can be written as ordered sums in $n + 1$ ways ($n$ from powers less than or equal to $2^{k-1}$, plus the $1$ way that is just $2^k$). Thus, $N(k+1) = (n+1)^2$.

$$N(k+1) = \left(N(k)+1\right)^2$$

Find $N(1)$. Then you should be able to find $N(10)$ by recursively applying the identity above.

Comment: Dear Zubin : I don't think this is right. Did you check for small values?

Comment: Your formula keeps notes from the first and second halves separate; this means you're overcounting by quite a lot.

Comment: I assumed that the order in which you write the sum matters (which is why I use "ordered sum" throughout the answer). If that isn't what the question was intended to count, then I suppose the solution answers a different question.

Comment: ...which leads to the conclusion that it has no place as an answer here.